# Unable to intantiate Action Struts 2, Spring

Tags: java, spring, struts2

I try to edit a class in project by adding value from configuration file.

the configuration:

```
...
account_default = 51e7fae0
...
...
```

at first on applicationContext.xml I add `${account_default}`:

```
<bean id="orgCertAction" class="com.xxxx.xxxxx.xxx.actions.Organization" scope="prototype">
  <constructor-arg  ref="Mgr"/>
  <constructor-arg  ref="Operator"/>
  <constructor-arg  ref="user"/>
  <constructor-arg  ref="Documents"/>
  <constructor-arg  ref="signer"/>
  <constructor-arg><value>${account_default}</value></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

and the bean definition ( the constructor) I add the accountDef:

```
public Organization(Organization Mgr,
    Operator raMgr, UserManager userMgr,
    Documents regDocs, SignerManager raSigner,
    SignManager signMgr, String accountDef)
{
    ..
    ...
    ....
    this.accountId = accountDef;
}
```

I get this stack:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.xxxxx.xxxxx.admin.actions.Organization': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 6 of type [java.lang.String]: : No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:741)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.autowireConstructor(ConstructorResolver.java:185)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireConstructor(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1114)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowire(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:350)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.spring.SpringObjectFactory.buildBean(SpringObjectFactory.java:179)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.spring.SpringObjectFactory.buildBean(SpringObjectFactory.java:154)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:171)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.DefaultActionFactory.buildAction(DefaultActionFactory.java:22)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildAction(ObjectFactory.java:141)
at com.xxxxx.xxxxx.admin.server.CustomSpringObjectFactory.buildAction(CustomSpringObjectFactory.java:50)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.createAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:297)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.init(DefaultActionInvocation.java:397)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:194)
at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.prepare(StrutsActionProxy.java:63)
at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsActionProxyFactory.java:37)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(DefaultActionProxyFactory.java:58)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:552)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:440)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:926)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoSuchBeanDefinitionException(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1100)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:960)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:855)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveAutowiredArgument(ConstructorResolver.java:805)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.createArgumentArray(ConstructorResolver.java:733)
... 62 more
[3553-3] ERROR Jan 07 17:52:49 - Exception occurred during processing request: Unable to intantiate Action!
Unable to intantiate Action!
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.createAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:299)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.init(DefaultActionInvocation.java:397)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxy.prepare(DefaultActionProxy.java:194)
at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxy.prepare(StrutsActionProxy.java:63)
at org.apache.struts2.impl.StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(StrutsActionProxyFactory.java:37)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(DefaultActionProxyFactory.java:58)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.serviceAction(Dispatcher.java:552)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.ExecuteOperations.executeAction(ExecuteOperations.java:77)
at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:99)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:330)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:118)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:154)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.www.BasicAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(BasicAuthenticationFilter.java:150)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:199)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:110)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192)
at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:344)
at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:261)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:440)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHandlerCollection.java:230)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.java:114)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:926)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:549)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:212)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at org.mortbay.io.nio.SelectChannelEndPoint.run(SelectChannelEndPoint.java:410)
at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.java:582)
Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.xxxxx.xxxxx.admin.actions.Organization
at java.lang.Class.newInstance0(Class.java:342)
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:310)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:151)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.spring.SpringObjectFactory.buildBean(SpringObjectFactory.java:189)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.spring.SpringObjectFactory.buildBean(SpringObjectFactory.java:154)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildBean(ObjectFactory.java:171)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.factory.DefaultActionFactory.buildAction(DefaultActionFactory.java:22)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.ObjectFactory.buildAction(ObjectFactory.java:141)
at com.xxxxx.xxxxx.admin.server.CustomSpringObjectFactory.buildAction(CustomSpringObjectFactory.java:50)
at com.opensymphony.xwork2.DefaultActionInvocation.createAction(DefaultActionInvocation.java:297)
... 52 more
```

Comment: How did you add your configuration file?

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to add a `public` default constructor for the action class. Because *Struts* is responsible to instantiate an action bean, as you have seen in the exception, it can do it if you provide the no-arg constructor. If you want the action beans being managed by Spring, you should provide bean id in the class attribute of the action configuration.

Comment: I update the stack trace...
I see the exeption:
    org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.xxxx.xxxx.admin.actions.Organization': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with index 6 of type [java.lang.String]: : No qualifying bean of type [java.lang.String] found for dependency: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency. Dependency annotations: {}; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException...

Comment: If the last argument is a property value you should define a property placeholder congfigurer in the application context.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to define a separed bean passed like a ref on arg like that:

```
  <constructor-arg ref="str" />

  </bean>
    <bean id="str" class="java.lang.String">
    <constructor-arg value="${account_default}"/>
  </bean>
```

thank's to all

Comment: Whole bean for a String value. Maybe you need to examine `constructor-arg` tag for other attributes besides `ref`.